# How to mark every non duplicate row in MySQL? (Merge Select and Update Statement)

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates, unique

I am using this query to get all non duplicate entrys in a database:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(title) as cnt
FROM my_table.books
GROUP BY title
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt;
```

I created a new column `no_duplicate` of type `tinyint(1)` in which I want to mark every row as `1`, that is unique (every output of the query above).

Is it possible to nest an Update with the query above? Or is there an even more elegant way?

Comment: Is this a one time thing, or will you run this query a lot?

Comment: @mazzzzz: It will be a onetime thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
update books set
no_duplicate = 1;

update books set
no_duplicate = 0
where title in (select title from (
  SELECT title, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM books
  GROUP BY title
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x);
```

I did it in two steps for efficiency, since it is much more likely to have no duplicates (reasonable assumption), the `WHERE title IN` list will be small and therefore fast.

Comment: That is correct only 7000 entrys from nearly a million have duplicates... Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: Would it be a performance boost if you replace the second `COUNT(*)` (behind the `HAVING`) by `cnt`?

Comment: @Aufwind Possibly, although the parser would probably do it anyway. This solution however will run with any SQL server (not all SQL flavours allow referencing a column alias in the HAVING clause). It definitely won't be slower and since you're on mysql, might as well do it.

Answer (score 0):

update books
set no_dublicate = 1
where title in (select title from books group by title having count(*) < 2)